# jpa and hibernate compare timestamp to a certain number of day

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to delete some rows after some days in jpa.

```
@Repository
public interface JpaTableRepository extends JpaRepository<TableEntity, String>
{
   @Query("DELETE FROM TABLE t WHERE lastChange > :numberOfDays")
   void delete(@Param("numberOfDays") int numberOfDays);
}
```

`numberOfDays` may be 10 Days. While `numberOfDays`is a int, `lastChange` is a TimeStamp (datetime).

```
@Entity(name = "Table")
public class TableEntity
{
   @Id
   private String id;
   @UpdateTimestamp
   private Timestamp lastChange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date operations is limited in JPA, but you could use Java methods.

Service :

```
int numberOfDays = 10;
LocalDateTime dateTimeMinusTenDays = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(numberOfDays);

repository.delete(dateTimeMinusTenDays);
```

Repository :

```
@Query("DELETE FROM TABLE t WHERE lastChange > :startingLimitDateTime")
void delete(@Param("startingLimitDateTime") LocalDateTime startingLimitDateTime);
```

(It requires to change lastChange type to a `java.time.LocalDateTime`)

Comment: LocalDateTime is probably not the right parameter typ: `IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2023-07-03T10:43:07.953401500] did not match expected type [java.util.Date`